# Fui bloqueado de postar e responder! O que fazer?

Tags: debate

Ontem, fui bloqueado de fazer e responder perguntas devido a uma má aceitação, pela comunidade, de uma pergunta mal formulada.

Sei que o bloqueio foi automático, realizado pelo algoritmo que detecta usuários que contribuem negativamente para a comunidade. Sei também que é reversível.

Mas não sei como reverter essa situação, já que não posso postar, nem responder, e a única pergunta mal recebida possui 4 negativações e apenas 2 aceitações.

Eu já reeditei diversas vezes a pergunta, e até marquei uma resposta como válida, mas não adiantou de nada. Continuo bloqueado.

A pergunta a que me refiro é esta: [Como verificar se algum texto foi selecionado antes de copiá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/como-verificar-se-algum-texto-foi-selecionado-antes-de-copi%C3%A1-lo)

Comment: Relacionado (link do SOen porque não achei o equivalente em português): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Melhorar o conteúdo já postado. É a única forma. Ninguém pode reverter isso. Apagar o conteúdo só piora a situação, mostra que você aceita que está ruim e que não fará nada para arrumar.

Dê o seu melhor, mude quantas vezes forem necessárias para os conteúdos serem reabertos, ou ter votos mudados. Não é fácil. O ideal é não cair nisso. Infelizmente o sistema não avisa a pessoa que acontecerá isso com ela. Aparentemente o sistema quer mesmo que trave a pessoa que não se preocupa com seu conteúdo.

Não esqueça de restaurar qualquer coisa que tenha apagado. Você tem várias perguntas negativadas, só que elas foram apagadas, ou por você ou pelo sistema. Tem pergunta com -8 de pontuação. Tem resposta ruim apagada também.

Quanto mais consertar e reverter a situação maior a chance de ter o desbloqueio. Em muitos casos vai tentar arrumar e não dará certo, por isso o ideal é não deixar isso acontecer.

Fazer coisas aleatórias não vai ajudar. E não foque neste pergunta, como ela já teve respostas nem dá para melhorar muito. Tente consertar as outras com problemas.

Tente fazer suas perguntas da forma mais completa possível, dê informação de tudo o que tentou, dê cada detalhe, tente fazer um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). E foco no **mínimo**. As pessoas tendem pegar seu código e largar aqui no SOpt de qualquer jeito, sem tentar entender o problema, sem reduzir o código só para a parte que dá o problema, tendo que a pessoa que vai responder ter que ela ficar reduzindo, ou ter que verificar coisas que não estão com erro. Esse é o erro mais comum dos "programadores" que levam aos negativos. A pessoa não quer ou não sabe reduzir seu problema, porque ela na verdade está fazendo algo complexa sem ter aprendido programar, então ela só sabe lidar com o código que ela copiou de outro lugar sem entender o que está acontecendo ali. Em geral as pessoas não gostam de ajudar quem está neste ponto. Precisa entender o problema, e ajudar quem vai te ajudar. Sabe o que acontece quando a pessoa reduz o problema para o mínimo? Em grande parte das vezes ela acha o problema sem precisar postar a pergunta.

Se o problema é que a pessoa não consegue sequer reduzir é porque ela está fazendo algo que ela não está apta, aí ela precisa de formação e não é o SOpt que poderá dar isso a ela. O SOpt é para resolver problemas específicos em um código mínimo, não é formar programadores, ainda que se as pessoas lessem tudo o que é postado aqui poderiam ajudar na sua formação, tem conteúdo magnífico postado que ensina programar ou pelo menos como conseguir aprender mais.

Agora terá que contar com a boa vontade da comunidade em mudar o voto, para isto terá que demonstrar muito boa vontade.

E não tente criar outra conta para contornar o bloqueio, é considerado má fé e sua conta será suspensa e até destruída. Aí perderá qualquer chance de retorno adequado.

Comment: Vai ser difícil, mas espero conseguir reconquistar a confiança da comunidade. Até porque muita coisa que sei, aprendi aqui no SO. De fato, preciso estudar mais, fazer alguns cursos específicos, para não ficar caindo em erros bobos que não sei resolver justamente por falta e conhecimento naquela linguagem/tecnologia. Vou reabrir as perguntas negativas e tentar modificá-las, apesar de serem perguntas "inúteis" de um tempo em que eu realmente não sabia nada. Quando eu conseguir recuperar a permissão para postar e responder, vou me policiar bastante para não cometer os mesmo erros. Obrigado!

Comment: O problema não é o erro bobo, isso todo mundo cai, eu caio mesmo depois de 35 fazendo isso. Mas precisa ter fundamento, precisa conseguir postar sobre o problema de forma adequada. Isso sequer é sobre programação. Não avaliei seu conteúdo em detalhes, mas vi que tem coisa que atrai negativos (não entrei no mérito se são justos). Se serve de consolo hoje uns 70% das perguntas estão assim. Quem sabe o pessoal vê aqui e melhora. Mas novamente, as perguntas apagadas são as que mais estão te prejudicando. Responder você ainda pode. Isto pode ajudar. Mas cuidado para não piorar ;)

Comment: Com certeza será excelente que membros cujas postagens são negativadas visualizem esta postagem e consigam melhorá-las. Vou revisar todas as menhas perguntas excluídas. Vou responder a elas de forma a ajudar iniciantes que talvez encontre o mesmo "problema", e torcer para que a comunidade não me interprete mal. Vai ser trabalhos, mas é melhor que excluir a conta. Obrigado, @Maneiro, pelo seu suporte e compreensão. Quando alguém faz algo de errado, muitos estão prontos para apedrejar, poucos realmente estendem a mão para ajudar a se levantar. Mas espero melhorar minha situação.

Comment: Só cuidado para não achar que querem apedrejar, muitas vezes a pessoa só quer apontar os problemas, e muitas vezes elas estão cansadas de ter que lidar com tanta coisa com problema. Claro, tem alguns apedrejamentos também, mas isso é raro, e se acontecer de fato em geral não pode, e em certo grau pode acabar gerando punição.

Comment: Verdade! Preciso parar de achar que o mundo está contra a mim. rs

Comment: @PauloDosSantos sempre lembrando que o bloqueio "passa" com o tempo automaticamente, basta não ficar repetindo os mesmos problemas.

Comment: Obrigado, @Bacco! Já consigo postar e responder, e até aparece uma mensagem para que eu fique ainda mais atento quanto a isso:

"Aguarde! Algumas das suas perguntas não foram bem recebidas e você está prestes a ser bloqueado para perguntas.

Para ajudar a formular uma pergunta clara e útil, consulte: Como fazer uma boa pergunta?

Além disso, edite suas perguntas anteriores para melhorar a formatação e a clareza."

Comment: "*- Agora terá que contar com a boa vontade da comunidade em mudar o voto, para isto terá que demonstrar muito boa vontade.*" Seria interessante o site notificar os usuários que deram -1 na publicação. Quase sempre eles não voltam na pergunta para "revisar" o conteúdo e, caso adequado, mudar o voto. Quando ocorre a edição, vai para a página inicial e pronto. Se o sujeito não estiver ativo, lá se vai a chance do cara perder os -1... Exemplo claro é a própria pergunta do colega aí. Tem +5 e -4. É bem provável que esses 4 nunca irão revisar o voto. Sem falar que o povo segura o +1... @Maniero

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- já foi pedido várias vezes e recusado.