# Como faço para remover a restrição de respostas?

Tags: suporte, contas-usuário

"Não aceitamos mais perguntas desta conta. Consulte a Central de ajuda para saber mais."
Não consigo mais responder as questões. Como faço pra retirar essa restrição?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7621/112052

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade o seu veto é de perguntas, por algum motivo você foi penalizado. Tente começar a responder perguntas para melhorar a sua reputação.

**Como posso sair de um veto a perguntas?**

O veto será revogado automaticamente pelo sistema quando ele constatar que suas contribuições positivas ultrapassam as perguntas que foram mal recebidas.

Fonte: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Então complicado mesmo, da uma olhada nesse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7622/113075 que vai te ajudar

Comment: Ele está bloqueado para respostas, não para pergunta. E o link correto nesse caso é https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans